# MEANIO Cluster of 4 to run only once for a scheduled Job?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean.io

What I want to see happen is have the MEAN spin up all four of the clusters. then run a scheduled job to email my customers every day at 20:30 .Currently runs more than once.
How do I accomplish this?

```
'use strict';
var mean = require('meanio');
var cluster = require('cluster');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var z = schedule.scheduleJob('30 20 * * *', function() {
    console.log('test the scheduler')
});
if (cluster.isMaster) {


// Count the machine's CPUs
var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

// Create a worker for each CPU
for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    console.log ('forking ',i);
    cluster.fork();
}

// Listen for dying workers
cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
    // Replace the dead worker, we're not sentimental
    console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died :(');
    cluster.fork();

});


} else {

var workerId = 0;
if (!cluster.isMaster)
{
    workerId = cluster.worker.id;
}


  mean.serve({ workerid: workerId /* more options placeholder*/ }, function (app, config) {
        var port = config.https && config.https.port ? config.https.port : config.http.port;
        console.log('Mean app started on port ' + port + ' (' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ') cluster.worker.id:', workerId);
    });
}
```

OUTPUT

```
forking  0
forking  1
forking  2
forking  3
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 1
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 2
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 3
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 4
test the scheduler
test the scheduler
test the scheduler
test the scheduler
test the scheduler
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, are you asking why your scheduler runs more than once? if so, it's because `cluster.fork()` works exactly like the unix fork in that it creates another process that is essentially a copy of the current one. Each process is going to schedule a job in it's own frame of reference and each one is going to execute that job. You might want to make sure that you only schedule jobs in the master process by moving the scheduling inside of `if(cluster.isMaster) {`.

By doing this you can instruct the master to dispatch jobs to workers. You will have to add the load balancing yourself, though.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider working with a job queue for this and instead of mailing directly place in queue and the process from there.
Before you addtoQueue see if the existing task is already there and thus avoid multiple instances.
I've used [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) and heard good things about [busmq](https://github.com/capriza/node-busmq)